# C# drawing Rectangle with precision coordinates. How?

Tags: c#

How do I draw a Rectangle in C# with precision coordinates?

Example:

```
Rectangle test1 = new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height);
```

**Width** and **Height** values seem to **have to be integers**.

Is it possible to give Rectangle, **inch size coordinates** somehow?

```
Rectangle test2 = new Rectangle(100, 50, 1.93inches, 0.52inches);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to convert know the conversion between inches and pixels, which depends on the screen resolution. I suppose you could do this:

```
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
var dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
var dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
var rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 50, Math.Round(1.93 * dpiX), Math.Round(0.52 * dpiY));
```